# Search bar with auto-text suggestion in text suggestion in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have created a form in SwiftUI, now I am trying to add a search bar and make the List searchable without system built NavigationView. I was wondering is there any possible way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is you can customise TextField in SwiftUI, via text field text to filter data.

```
struct Sample006: View {
    @State var dataSource: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var filterData: [String] = []
    @State var filterText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Input Text", text: self.$filterText)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        
            Form {
                ForEach(filterData, id: \.self) { data in
                    Text(data)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            reset()
        }
        .onChange(of: filterText) { newValue in
            guard !newValue.isEmpty else {
                reset()
                return
            }
        
            filterData = dataSource.filter { text in
                text == newValue
            }
        }
    }

    private func reset() {
        filterData = dataSource
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: clean solution. Thanks man